# Solutions to $X^3 = I_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Show that there are an infinite number of solutions to $X^3 = I_2$ in $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

$\operatorname{det} (X) = 1$ because $X^3 = I_2$ and $\operatorname{det} (X) \in \mathbb{Q}$

$X^2 = X^{-1}$ and, using Cayley-Hamilton $X^2 = \operatorname{tr}(X) X - I_2$ so $$ X^{-1} = \operatorname{tr}(X)X - I_2 $$ but when i try to solve this equation the solution it gives do not verify $X^3 = I_2$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $X$ is a solution then $X^2$ is also a solution.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah But that produces only one extra solution corresponding to a solution that is not $I_2$.  Repeated squaring doesn't help, because $X^4 = X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any matrices with characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+\lambda+1$ will do: both eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^3=1$. For example, for any integer $n$ one can take
$$
X=\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
n, & -1-n-n^2\\
1, & -1-n
\end{array}\right].
$$

Answer (score 3):

The general solution, if that is what you want, is (apart from $I$ itself)

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-1-a\\\end{pmatrix}$, where $bc=-(a^2+a+1)$.

Comment: Not quite general, as it doesn't include $I_2$ itself.

Comment: Quite right. Just looked at my notes and see I omitted $a=d=1,b=c=0$ as I typed the solutions up.

Answer (score 1):

Cayley-Hamilton gives us $X^2-\text{tr}(X)X+I = 0$, from which we find $X(X-\text{tr}(X)I) = -I$, and hence $X^{-1} = \text{tr}(X)I-X$. Letting
\begin{align*}
X = \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix} \right)
\end{align*}
we get the following system of equations
\begin{align*}
a^2+bc =& d \\
b(a+d) =& -b \\
c(a+d) =& -c \\
d^2+bc =& a
\end{align*}
Which yields either $X = I$ or 
\begin{align*}
X = \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & -1-a
\end{matrix} \right)
\end{align*}, where $bc = -1-a-a^2$